# Upload bandwidth limits on amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3

Are there any (documented or undocumented) **upload** bandwidth (per account/ip?) restrictions on Amazon S3?

I'm potentially looking at storing 200mbits constantly but I figure Amazon may have an issue with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any documented limits and [tests](http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/) seem to suggest that the maximum throughput was greater than 8gbit in 2011.